# v5.0 to 20.2 - columns displaying as html source

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an APEX application that was exported from v5.0 on-premise instance and imported to v20.2 Cloud/PaaS/ATP instance. Just working on getting the pages to run properly.

One classic report region is showing the column values as html source instead of the values. I vaguely recall this happening in v5.0, which was corrected by selecting Display As: Standard Report Column under column attributes, but I don't see this same option under v20.2. Can anyone help.

[image]

SQL Source:

```
select 
  apex_item.text(p_idx       => 12, 
                 p_value     => nvl(c002,'0'), 
                 p_size      =>  20, 
                 p_maxlength => 2) duplicate_qty, 
  apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx            => 14, 
                      p_value          => seq_id, 
                      p_checked_values => CASE c003 WHEN '1' THEN seq_id END) analog_placement_flag, 
  apex_item.checkbox2(p_idx            => 16, 
                      p_value          => seq_id, 
                      p_checked_values => CASE c004 WHEN '1' THEN seq_id END) delete_row 
 from apex_collections   
 where collection_name = 'TEMPCOL';
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Navigate to column's property palette (right-hand side of the screen)
- scroll down to "Security" section
- switch **Escape special characters** property OFF

That's all.